# How to report progress from long-running PostgreSQL function to client

Tags: .net, sql, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I have a C# client application that uses Npgsql to call a plpgsql function in PostgreSQL 9.1.4. The function takes a very long time and I'd like to report progress to the client in some way. How should I do this?

The LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism sounds perfect for this, except that the whole thing runs inside a transaction and NOTIFY events are not sent until the end of the transaction, which is useless to me.

The other thing I've tried is RAISE NOTICE, which I can process on the client, but even those notices seem to be buffered for a while and sent in batches. It's better than nothing, but not ideal. Is there any way I can "flush" them, so they're sent to the client immediately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing better than RAISE NOTICE.

These signals are not buffered - and they are asynchronous - you have issue in notices processing in your application probably.

Comment: With PostgreSQL 8.4 and above you can also supply an error code to RAISE NOTICE, which makes it easier to tell the difference between progress messages and other notices that might be emitted.

Comment: You're right, it turns out that the NOTICEs *were* being delivered as they were raised, but there was a very strange slowdown in the function, which didn't happen when I ran the same query directly. I've figured out a workaround for it now.

Comment: RAISE NOTICE has relative significant overhead - it is network handshake between client and server. I usually doesn't raise notice every iteration, but I notice every thousand iteration.

Comment: I wrote function counter for long time transformation SQL functions - maybe it can be useful for you http://okbob.blogspot.cz/2010/11/new-version-of-pst-collection-is.html#links

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @Pavel's excellent point about `RAISE NOTICE`, there's another classic technique used to monitor query progress in Pg. It's a bit of a hack, but it's quite effective.

You can exploit the fact that changes to sequences are immediately visible everywhere to expose the progress of a function to the outside. Either use a hard-coded sequence and ensure the function is not called concurrently, or pass the progress monitoring sequence name into the function.

Your function can call `nextval(seqname)` at each iteration, and interested parties can examine the state of the sequence with `SELECT last_value FROM seqname` from another session.

You can make the sequence a count-down to completion by setting it up with

```
create sequence test maxvalue 2147483647 increment by -1;
```

and calling `setval('seqname', num_items)` at the start of your function. It'll then count down toward zero with each `nextval` call. 2147483647 is [maxint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html), by the way.

Needless to say this isn't portable, and there's no guarantee that `SELECT`ing from a sequence will always work this way. It's darn handy, though.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way would be to split your pgsql function into multiple sub functions, than call them sequentially, application-side, managing transaction scope in the application.

Comment: Thanks, but in this particular case it would not be simple, I can assure you. :) Any other ways?

Comment: Not that I can think of, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT ''progress: ' || progress_variable || ''') TO ''d:\progress.txt''';
```

inside your function to write current progress to a text file.